# C# XmlSerializer an object with various ways attributes setting

Tags: c#, xmlserializer

I have a class definition like this

```
public class ScenarioModel {
    public string Version { get; set; }
}
```

I want to serialize an instance of this class to 2 various format XML files.
(using `System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer`)

File 1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Scenario>
    <Version>1.0.0</Vesion>
</Scenario>
```

File 2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Scenario version="1.0.0">
</Scenario>
```

How can I do settings for my `ScenarioModel` class definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Model:

```
[XmlRoot("Scenario")]
public class ScenarioModel
{
    public string Version { get; set; }
}
```

Program.cs:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ScenarioModel model = new ScenarioModel { Version = "1.0.0" };

    XmlSerializer ser = null;
    XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
    ns.Add(string.Empty, string.Empty);

    Console.WriteLine("File 1\n==================");
    ser = new XmlSerializer(model.GetType());
    ser.Serialize(Console.Out, model, ns);

    Console.WriteLine("\n\nFile 2\n==================");
    XmlAttributeOverrides attrOverrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
    XmlAttributes attr = new XmlAttributes { XmlAttribute = new XmlAttributeAttribute("Version") };
    attrOverrides.Add(model.GetType(), "Version", attr);
    ser = new XmlSerializer(model.GetType(), attrOverrides);
    ser.Serialize(Console.Out, model, ns);

    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Should give you something like:

```
File 1
==================
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Scenario>
  <Version>1.0.0</Version>
</Scenario>

File 2
==================
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Scenario Version="1.0.0" />
```

Comment: thanks for your solution. Sorry to bother you, I have one more question, my team want to use `.xsd` file to describe XML format instead of setting in `ScenarioModel.cs` file. Is it possible?

Comment: @anzvanie glad to hear that. But speak to `.xsd` file, I am not familiar with it :(